# an example to coda consonant in german language wals chapter 16

Tags: linguistic-typology, rhythm

hello could someone give an example to coda consonant in german language  referring to [WALS Chapter 16](http://wals.info/chapter/16) : here is what I did but it might be wrong : Value: Coda consonant. A coda is a post-vocalic consonant. In particular absence of a long vowel, coda consonants are used to add weight to a syllable.

Example: In German words like ‘Tor’ [tʰoːɐ̯] ('gate') or in ‘Würde’ [ˈvʏɐ̯də], the consonant /r/ sound takes up vowel form /ɐ̯/. So here, the /r/ sound is behaving like a coda consonant.

what do you think let me know your opinions! either correct what I did or come up with something new please!!! thanks!

Comment: By your definition, *t* in *spricht* is not in the coda (*ch* is not "vocalic") and *b* in *Abend* is. Both consequences are wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [German LU](http://german.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

A coda consonant is just a consonant at the end of a syllable, not more and not less. So the English word "less" has a coda consonant /s/.

The special development of syllable-final r in modern German has nothing to do with the definition of a coda consonant (and one might argue that the syllable does not end in a consonant at all in this case, but in a kind of diphthong).